# How to make a pointer point to any array element of a 2D array?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Coming straight to the point,

I want the character pointer `p` to point to the only array element that contains the character '`T`'.

```
char a[100][100];
char *p;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    if(a[i][j] == 'T')
      p = a[i][j];
```

P.S. I tried with various combinations of `*`, `**`, etc but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `a[i][j]` is char type so `&a[i][j]` is simpler way remember precedence of `[]` is higher then `&` so  `&a[i][j]` is correct without `()`. do you want any other technique? or any thing else

Comment: *"I tried with various combinations of `*`, `**`"* - Should have tried some combinations of `&`. ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use its address:

```
char a[100][100];
char *p;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    if(a[i][j] == 'T')
      p = &a[i][j];
```

`a[i][j]` is of type `char` and `p` is of type `char *`, which holds an address. To get the address of a variable, prepend it with `&`.

The `*` operator on a pointer works the other way round. If you would want to get the `'T'` back, you'd use:

```
 char theT = *p;
```

Answer (score 7):

there is another way to get it

```
char a[100][100];
char *p;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
       if(a[i][j] == 'T')
           p = a[i]+j;
```

By writing `p = a[i]+j;` you actually say, We have a pointer at the begging of an array called **a[i]** and you point to the position that is **j** times away from the begging of that array!

Answer (score -1):

change the if part as follows

```
  if(a[i][j] == 'T' ) {
       p = (char *) &a[i][j];
       i = 4; break;
  }
```