# Having Problems while calling pointers into function in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am having a trouble using pointers in function.

```
int old = Grid[x][y];
int new_one = Grid[x][y-1];
Crush_or_not = move(&old , &new_one);
y--;
```

Here I have a 2d array called Grid. I want to call a function called 'move'.

```
bool move(int *old_location, int *new_location)
{
    if (*new_location == 1)
    {
        *new_location = 3;
        *old_location = 1;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the compiler returns an error:

> error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string}) (int*, int*)’

So I don't quite understand why this would happen, can anyone help me?

Comment: Is function `move` declared before its usage?

Comment: My *guess* (what you get with no mcve). Wherever the first snippet resides, there is a `std::string` called `move` that is hiding your member function. If `move` were an unknown member, that's the error you would get (unknown function/identifier blah). That's not what you're getting.

Comment: Do you have `using namespace XXX;` in your code? (where XXX is anything).

Comment: apart from the function call compilation error, this code might not do what you expect: by reading two values from the grid array into `int` locals, the values updated in `move` will be written to `old` and `new_one`, but not update the grid position they were originally taken from.

Comment: does your code contain any unicode character yet?

Comment: @Martin York Yes I do have using namespace std.

Comment: @Cepheus I didn't declare it. Instead, I directly write it before the main function.

Comment: @dlatikay Yes, I noticed that. If I directly use &Grid[x][y], will the value be written in the array?

Comment: What is the type of `Crush_or_not`?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue Its a bool.

Comment: see: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065) You are importing from the standard namespace a bunch of functions called `move()`. The compiler is probebaly getting confused on which one to use. Stop using `using namespace std`. Or simply change the name of `move()` to something unique like: `updateInNewLocationIfOne()` as this actually describes what it does. Using the name `move()` to do the above is very non intuitive as its not actually a move its a conditional move based on a test. Make your function name reflect that.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks! It works perfectly now.

Comment: @desantamichell [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985644/1132334)

Comment: Thanks, everyone! This problem is solved! : )